# Cannot figure out why List won't display data from ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript, mxml, arraycollection

I'm working on a flash cards application and am using an ArrayCollection of Objects to store each cards individual data.  When the user click the 'save' button, the text from the two textAreas and the 'title' textinput are stored in the AC as one object with .title, .side1 and .side2 properties that contain the text from the flash card.

I have made a List in a separate class I want to have display the title of each card the user has created, but after days of researching and looking around, I still cannot get the display to list the titles.
If anyone could point me in the right direction it would very appreciated.

**Part of my NewCard.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        import spark.effects.SlideViewTransition;

        import views.MyCards;


        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void   // back button
        {

            {   
                navigator.pushView(views.MyFlashCardsHome, event.relatedObject);
            }
        }
        protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void  // save button
        {

            var myc:MyCards = new MyCards();
            var card:Object = new Object();

            myc.add();
            titleCard.text = "Card Added!";

        }

        protected function button3_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void  // flip button
        {
            rotateEffect.play();
            if(rotateEffect.isPlaying)
            {
                if(mtext1.visible)
                {
                    mtext2.visible = true;
                    mtext1.visible = false;
                    //mtext2.text = "two";
                    groupt.layoutDirection = "rtl";
                }
                else
                {
                    mtext2.visible = false;
                    mtext1.visible = true;
                    //mtext1.text = "one";
                    groupt.layoutDirection = "rtl";

                }
            }

        }


        protected function button4_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void  // push home button
        {
            var slideViewTransition:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition( 300, SlideViewTransition.SLIDE_RIGHT);
            navigator.pushView(views.HomePage, event.relatedObject, slideViewTransition);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Rotate3D id="rotateEffect" duration="300" target="{groupt}" 
                angleYFrom="0" angleYTo="180" 
                autoCenterTransform="true"
                effectStart="flipButton.enabled=false;"
                effectEnd="flipButton.enabled=true;"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button height="50" label="Study" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" cornerRadius="0"
              fontFamily="_sans"/>
    <s:Button height="62"  click="button4_clickHandler(event)" cornerRadius="0" skinClass="skins.homeButtonSkin"/>
</s:actionContent>

<s:Image x="0" y="-80" width="1024" height="600" source="@Embed('mainapp1.jpg')"/>

<s:TextInput id="titleCard" x="240" y="10" height="62" chromeColor="#515851" color="#060606"
             contentBackgroundAlpha="1.0" contentBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" text="Title"/>

<s:SkinnableContainer
    id = "groupt" x="161" y="88" width="703" height="357"  >

    <s:TextArea id="mtext2" visible="false" x="0" y="0" width="703" height="357" 
                color="#000000" contentBackgroundAlpha="1.0" 
                contentBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" editable="true" enabled="true"
                paddingTop="70" text="Enter Text Here: (Side Two)" textAlign="center"/>

    <s:TextArea id="mtext1" x="0" y="0" width="703" height="357" color="#030303"
                contentBackgroundAlpha="1.0" contentBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" editable="true"
                enabled="true" fontFamily="Arial" fontStyle="normal" fontWeight="normal"
                lineThrough="false" paddingTop="70" text="Enter Text Here: (Side One)"
                textAlign="center" textDecoration="none" verticalAlign="middle"/>

</s:SkinnableContainer>
<s:Button x="763" y="10" height="62" label="Save" click="button2_clickHandler(event)"
          cornerRadius="0" fontFamily="_sans"/>

<s:Label x="5" y="34" color="#49A6D6" fontFamily="Georgia" fontStyle="italic" fontWeight="bold"
         paddingLeft="25" text="My"/>

<s:Label x="68" y="34" width="73" color="#E0B338" fontFamily="Georgia" fontStyle="italic"
         fontWeight="bold" paddingLeft="0" text="Flash"/>

<s:Label x="138" y="34" color="#49A6D6" fontFamily="Georgia" fontStyle="italic" fontWeight="bold"
         text="Cards!"/>

<s:Button id="flipButton" x="468" y="460" height="50" label="Flip" chromeColor="#2428D8"
          click="button3_clickHandler(event)" fontFamily="_sans"/>
```

**Part of my MyCards.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
        import flash.filesystem.File;
        import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
        import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.collections.ArrayList;
        import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.effects.SlideViewTransition;
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        import views.NewCard;



        public var file:File;
        public var fileStream:FileStream;
        public var fileName:String = "Initial String";
        private var directory:String = "SimpleSaveFromAIR";

        public var nc:NewCard = new NewCard();
        public var card:Object = new Object();


        [Bindable]
        public var cards:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();



        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void  // pushed home button
        {
            var svt:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition(300, SlideViewTransition.SLIDE_RIGHT);
            navigator.pushView(views.HomePage, event.relatedObject, svt);
        }



        public function add():void
        {
            var nc:NewCard = new NewCard();
            var card:Object = new Object();

            card.fTitle = nc.titleCard.text; //adding text to object from NewCard.mxml class
            cards.addItem(card); 


        }


        /* public function save():void
        {
            file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(directory + "/" + fileName);
            fileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            fileStream.writeObject(cards);
            fileStream.close();
        }  */

        public function myCardsList_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            cards.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, refreshList);
            trace(cards.list); // no data at all shows up here

        }

        private function refreshList(event:CollectionEvent):void
        {
            trace("cards refreshed "+ cards.list);
        }

        public function testButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            card.fTitle = nc.titleCard.text;
            cards.addItem(card);
            //trace(cards.list); // add data that has been added shows up here

        }



    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button id="testButton" label="Button" click="testButton_clickHandler(event)" />
    <s:Button label="Delete"/>
    <s:Button label="Home" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" skinClass="skins.homeButtonSkin"/>
</s:actionContent>

<s:Image x="0" y="-80" height="603" source="mainapp1.jpg"/>

<s:List id="myCardsList" x="10" y="10" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="1004"
        height="500"  dataProvider="{cards}" labelField="fTitle"
        enabled="true" >
    </s:List>
```

Again any help is greatly appreciated.

**CardVO class:**

```
package
```

{
    public class CardVO
    {
        private var _title:String;    //values returned from getter/setter functions
        private var _side1:String;
        private var _side2:String;

```
    //get the "Title", "Side1" and "Side2" values from textAreas (later) and set them 
    // above variables

    public function get Title():String {return _title;} 
    public function set Title(value:String):void { _title = value; }

    public function get Side1():String {return _side1;}
    public function set Side1(value:String):void {_side1 = value;}

    public function get Side2():String {return _side2;}
    public function set Side2(value:String):void {_side2 = value;}


}
```

}

** NewCard snippet:**

```
[Bindable]
        public var myCard:CardVO = new CardVO(); // create new instance of CardVO
```

....

```
    <!-- text property of mtext1 and mtext2 is bound and returned to the get/set functions in CardVO in the 'change' event-->
    <!-- change sets setter values to those retrieved from textAreas-->

    <s:TextArea id="mtext2" visible="false" x="0" y="0" width="703" height="357" 
                color="#000000" contentBackgroundAlpha="1.0" 
                contentBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" editable="true" enabled="true"
                paddingTop="70" text="{myCard.Side2}" change = "{myCard.Side2 = mtext2.text}"
                textAlign="center"/>

    <s:TextArea id="mtext1" x="0" y="0" width="703" height="357" color="#030303"
                contentBackgroundAlpha="1.0" contentBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" editable="true"
                enabled="true" fontFamily="Arial" fontStyle="normal" fontWeight="normal"
                lineThrough="false" paddingTop="70" text="{myCard.Side1}" change="{myCard.Side1 = mtext1.text}"
                textAlign="center" textDecoration="none" verticalAlign="middle"/>

</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

**MyCards snippet:**

```
public function add():void
        {

            var nc:NewCard = new NewCard(); // create new instance of NewCard
            cards.addItem(nc.myCard); // add new Item to ArrayCollection 'cards'
            trace(cards.list);
        }
```

**Mycards List code**

```
<s:List id="myCardsList" x="10" y="10" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="1004"
        height="500" change="myCardsList_changeHandler(event)" dataProvider="{cards}"
        enabled="true" >
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:MobileItemRenderer label="{data.title}"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
```

Comment: Your code samples do not show how MyCards.mxml can see `cards`

Comment: @Slomojo, Sorry. I updated the code samples to include how MyCards sees cards.

Comment: You need to post a more complete code sample. If you can see a `NewCard` entry component on the screen, we can't see how you've done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `List` component you should be able to specify the field you want to show using the `labelField` property.

```
<s:List id="myFlashCardList" dataProvider="{cards}" labelField="fTitle"/>
```

**EDIT 2:**

It seems like what you're trying to do here (and correct me if I'm wrong), is to have the user create a new instance of the `NewCard` object and then add it to your `cards` ArrayCollection. Your list then displays the titles of the cards the user has created.

Assuming this is the case, I think you're making it a little complicated than it needs to be. ArrayCollections can hold any type of class or object so you don't have to create a new `Object` and add it to the ArrayCollection every time they add a new card.

What I would do is create a `Card` class and populate it using your NewCard component.  When you're done, you add that Card class to the ArrayCollection. Something like this:

**The CardVO class:**

```
package
{
  public class CardVO
  {
    private var _title:String;
    private var _side1:String;
    private var _side2:String;


    public function get Title():String { return _title; }
    public function set Title(value:String):void { _title = value; }

    public function get Side1():String { return _side1; }
    public function set Side1(value:String):void { _side1 = value; }

    public function get Side2():String { return _side2; }
    public function set Side2(value:String):void { _side2 = value; }
  }
}
```

Then in your NewCard.mxml file you use a CardVO to store the data:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        ...

        [Bindable] public var myCard:CardVO = new CardVO();

        ...
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:SkinnableContainer id = "groupt">
    <s:TextArea id="mtext2" text="{myCard.Side2}" change="{myCard.Side2 = mtext2.text}"/>

    <s:TextArea id="mtext1" text="{myCard.Side1}" change="{myCard.Side1 = mtext1.text}" />
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

Then after the user has created their card, you pass the CardVO object to your ArrayCollection.

```
...
public function add():void
{
  var nc:NewCard = new NewCard();

  cards.addItem(nc.myCard);
}
...
```

This is a very abbreviated example so feel free to ask any questions that don't make sense. You should also look into [Data Binding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7fff.html) if you haven't already done so. It will save you a lot of time and make your apps more efficient once you get the hang of it. :)

Comment: @JasonTowne : Thanks for the reply.  I added a labelField into the List: as LabelField = "ftitle" and still didn't have anything displayed in the List.

Comment: @Fran71, I updated my answer after your edit. Let me know if this helps. :)

Comment: @JasonTowne, Ok by changing to cards.addItem(card) the word Title appears in the list exactly like I want, but it seems to only be there because I added it inside the testButton_clickHandler event.  How come it doesn't display 'Title' when I call the add() function inside MyCards from NewCard?  =)

Comment: @Fran71, Without looking at the `add()` method in `NewCard`, I can't exactly tell you why. To be honest I'm not exactly sure how `NewCard.mxml` relates to `MyCards.mxml`. You create a new `NewCard` object in `MyCards.mxml` but I can't see where it's used.

Comment: @JasonTowne, I updated the first post to include the add().  It's in MyCard.  The NewCard Object is used in the testButton_click() in order to be able to get the text from the textinput that is in NewCard.  If I'm thinking this through right, of course.

Comment: @Jason, @Fran - It definitely looks to me like the problem is with `NewCard` - in the `add()` method, `NewCard` can't possibly have any content, this is why `card.fTitle = nc.titleCard.text;` does nothing of use.

Comment: @Fran - Instead you should be getting a reference to a `NewCard` instance that is seen by the user... (I notice you also have `nctitle` defined, this is also not seen by the user, at least judging by the code posted.)

Comment: @Fran - Make sure you have a `NewCard` component on screen, with an `id` or an instance var, and then use that as the reference when getting the title.

Comment: @Slomojo, I'm still pretty new to ActionScript and MXML, what do you mean by 'seen by the user'?  How would I get a NewCard component on screen without declaring it like I did?  Thanks again for helping. =) (I updated the code up top with the rest of NewCard.

Comment: @Fran71, I added another really rough example to my answer. I think you're probably making this harder than it needs to be. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: @JasonTowne, I built in your recommendation into my project and am (pretty) sure I understand what's going on. i added the new snippets below the op. I commented on the adjustment to make sure I understood so correct if I'm wrong on any of them. Interestingly enough I was looking into getters and setters just a few minutes ago. Also, I'm getting 2 warnings in NewCard that the program "won't be able to detect data binding assignments" for the 2 TextAreas. How do I make those Bindable? Edit: Figured it out. I made the CardVO class [Bindable]. But still now display in the MyCards list

Comment: @Fran71, Sounds like you're getting the hang of things. Did we answer your questions or is there anything else you needed help with? :)

Comment: @JasonTowne, Yeah you guys have really helped out.  =)  One last thing, is there something I'm not doing right with updating MyCards when it's loaded on the screen to display the List?  I've been trying for hours now, and still can't get anything to appear. (current List code added above.)

Comment: @Fran71, Is there a reason you're using a `MobileItemRenderer` in your list?

Comment: @JasonTowne, it's a mobile App.

Comment: @Fran71, I gotcha. Remember that Actionscript is case sensitive so try `data.Title` instead of `data.title`.

Comment: @Fran71, I'm heading out. I'll check back in and see if you have any more questions. Since this is your first questions, it's typically appreciated if you click the green checkmark next to the answer that helped solve your problem. It helps other with a similar question find the answer that could help them as well. If I helped answer your question, I'd certainly appreciate that checkmark and an upvote. :)

Comment: @JasonTowne, Alright thanks again for all your help.  Much appreciated.  I'll keep at it.  =D

Comment: @Fran71, Sounds good. If you have need any more help just post another question. I (or another SO user) will do our best to help. :)